# Angular Buttons

Tags: angular

I am new to angular  and was practicing making buttons. I am able to make simple buttons and handle click events but now I trying to make three parallel button but not able to do so. Page I want to achieve is as follows:

---

```
                               My Title:



square buttons-1             square button-2                square buttomn-3
```

By looking at angular docs I am able to make those buttons but  I am not getting how to make  parallel square button page  like above so that I can handle click of  button.

Comment: Provide the code for reference (so that we can point out the issue). How can we help u with your code when you wont share any :)

Comment: I have code for simple button but don't know how to code for above scenario

Comment: I havent given any negative points Zaib333. Please verify your claim once. I tried to help. Thanks :) I can see that u have an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is simply HTML & CSS, there nothing to do with TypeScript and Angular:

```css
.title{
 text-align:center;
 
}

.button-wrapper{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">Your title<div>
<div class="button-wrapper">
    <button>Your Button 1</button>
    <button>Your Button 2</button>
    <button>Your Button 3</button>
</div>
```